# react-bootstrap - custom container class for navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm developing a project using `react-bootstrap` and I notice that the `Navbar` component insert the contents of the navbar into a `container` div and I was wondering if there is any way to override this and give a custom class?

I see that you can add a custom element with the attribute `componentClass` but if I add this then I lose all the `nav` styling. `componentClass="nav custom-class"` throws an error.

Comment: i'm facing the same challenge, have you found an elegant solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I now can't remember the reason that I originally asked this question! I don't think that I resolved it and perhaps just lived with the limitation for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute bsClass instead, like `bsClass='nav custom-class'`. See reference [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs-props).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that just adds the classes `nav custom-class` to the `nav` component. I want the `nav` component to stay as it is but the immediate child to it:
`<div class="container">`
to be 
`<div class="custom-class">`.

Comment: If that's the case the only way I can think of is saving a reference to the `navbar` component when rendering and then adding the extra class in the 'componentDidMount' method.

Comment: Ok, I'll save that as a last resort and hope that someone comes through with a different solution. Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to override the css, like:

```
.navbar > .container {
    /* your stuff */
}
```